# Failed to start server. Error: Invalid argument

Tags: docker, powershell, rest, tensorflow

I am currently working with TensorFlow serving and while running a command I encountered an error

**Step 1:- I pulled tensorflow/serving image using**

```
docker pull tensorflow/pull
```

**Step 2:- I made a project where I save the TF model in a directory:**

```
C:/Code/potato-disease:
```

**Step 3:- After running the command :-**

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8505:8505 -v C:/Code/potato-disease:/potato-disease tensorflow/serving --rest_api_port=8505 --model_config_file=/potato-disease/models.config
```

**Error:-**

```
Failed to start server. Error: Invalid argument: Expected model potatoes_model to have an absolute path or URI; got base_path()=C:/Code/potato-disease/saved_models
2022-03-16 03:21:46.161233: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:279] Unload all remaining servables in the manager.
```

**My models.config file**

```
model_config_list {
 config {
    name: 'potatoes_model'
    base_path: 'C:/Code/potato-disease/saved_models'
    model_platform: 'tensorflow'
    model_version_policy: {all: {}}
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your `models.config` config and put `/potato-disease/saved_models` as a `base_path` since it'll be the docker that will interpret your code it should have propper arguments depending of it's environnement, since it's running inside docker the absolute path should be considering that.